# Unable to start google cloud shell through gcloud cmd

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-shell, gcloud-cli

```
 ~ % gcloud cloud-shell ssh                     
Automatic authentication with GCP CLI tools in Cloud Shell is disabled. To enable, please rerun command with `--authorize-session` flag.
Starting your Cloud Shell machine...
ERROR: (gcloud.cloud-shell.ssh) HttpError accessing <https://cloudshell.googleapis.com/v1/users/me/environments/default:start?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Fri, 15 Sep 2023 14:20:04 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 500}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
>
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

Above is the error I got, same issue occurs if I switch internet

Comment: Make sure you have the latest gclould cli. Also try removing your public key: `.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub` and `.ssh/google_compute_engine`

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.